# How to pass to the controller method request body?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using `play framework 2.8.x` and I need to pass to the controller request body. I want to do something like that:

```
public class HomeController extends Controller {
    public Result test(String tokenId) {
        ...
        return ok();
    }
}
```

and send request like that:
[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get it from `Request` object something like:

```java
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result index(Http.Request request) {
  JsonNode json = request.body().asJson();
  String tokenId = json .get("tokenId").asText();
  ...
  return ok();
}
```

Please, see official documentation for details: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaBodyParsers#Body-parsers

Hope this helps!

Comment: @John you are very welcome. I glad it was  helpfull